# specify nested template parameters for function call

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

How I can specify types for template function when I call it?

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

template <typename O, typename E, template <typename, typename> class VariantType>
VariantType<O, E> f(O o)
{
    return VariantType<O, E>{std::move(o)};
}

int main()
{
    boost::variant<int, std::string> res = 
     f<int, std::string, boost::variant<int, std::string>>(17);
}
```

clang reports such error(`clang++ -Wall -std=c++11 test.cpp`):

```
test.cpp: error: no matching function for call to 'f'
                boost::variant<int, std::string> res = f<int, std::string, boost::variant<int, std::string>>(17);
                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp: note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'VariantType'
VariantType<O, E> f(O o)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arity of the boost::variant template-class template argument list isn't two. So, fix it e.g. by changing `template <typename, typename>` to `template <typename...>`:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/921e571139f9091e)</kbd>**

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

template <typename O, typename E, template <typename...> class VariantType>
VariantType<O, E> f(O o)
{
    return VariantType<O, E>{std::move(o)};
}

int main()
{
    boost::variant<int, std::string> res = f<int, std::string, boost::variant>(17);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't. Declaring a template template parameter `template <typename, typename> class VariantType` as the third template parameter for `f` means that the third template argument for `f` should be a class *template*. `boost::variant` is a template. `boost::variant<int, std::string>` isn't a template anymore---it's a specialization of a template.

Comment: So it is impossible to call such function like `f`?

Comment: I am sorry, but `f<int, std::string, boost::variant>` also doesn't work. Can you show how fix my code?

Comment: @user1244932 You should post that as a new question.